# Garbage Collection of Objects passed as arguments and being set to null in a method

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have was trying to understand this question but could not get settled with the answer provided in the book. Can somebody explain to me?  Question is given bellow.

```
class CardBoard {
  Short story = 5;

  CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {
    cb = null;
    return cb;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
    c1 = null;
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

**When // do stuff is reached, how many objects are eligible for garbage collection?**

Given answer is **2 objects. Only one CardBoard object (c1) is eligible, but it has an associated Short wrapper object that is also eligible**

I dont understand why object c1 alone is eligible for garbage collection.

Two object are created, c1 and c2.

For object c3 we are passing c2 to c1.go() method. And that that is set to null and returned object is asigned to c3.

In the method c1.go(), object that cb reffering to (which by my undertanding, the same object that c2 reffering to ) is set as null. Won't that make the object that c2 reffering to will also be available for garbage collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is *pass-by-value*. When you do `CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);`, the instance pointed to by `c2` is passed to `go()` but the moment you do `cb=null`, the original `c2's cb` is NOT set to `null`, a new null reference `aconst_null` is pushed onto the stack and returned. Hence, there are only 2 objects (`Short` and `c1`) that are eligible for GC.

PS : As Andreas says, `Short` values are cached for values between -128 and 127 and hence in your case, the same `Short` instance will be reused. So only one object will be eligible for GC. If your `Short` value is out of that range, then 2 Objects will be eligible for GC.

Comment: I understand that the copy of the reference variable is passed in c1.go(c2), and that is copied to the reference variable cb. Won't those two reference variables be poiting to the same object in the heap?

Comment: @AnjJo - Yes, they will be. But when you do `cb=null`, the second reference doesn't point to the Original object anymore. It will point to `null`

Comment: Only the the reference of `cb` is set to `null`. But if we had tried to change an instance variable then both reference variable would still be referring to the same object. That is what you say right?

Comment: Yes. If the original object is changed, both references will still be pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass-by-value, so when you null out parameter `cb`, that does not change the value of variable `c2`.

The `go()` method call simply ends up returning `null`, leaving `c1` and `c2` unchanged.

So, when execution get to `// do stuff`, `c1` is null, `c2` refers to second object, and `c3` is null. Which means the first object is eligible for GC.

---

Since each object has a `Short` reference, you'd think that two objects will be freed (first object and its `story`), and two objects will remain (second object and its `story`), however that is not really true.

A `Short` value of 5 will not create a new instance of a `Short` object. Values between -128 and 127 (inclusive) are *cached*, and the cache values are permanent.

This means that the true answer is that only 2 objects were allocated, and the first object is eligible for GC. The `Short story` references don't allocate anything.

Comment: Yes. You are right `Short` field should not get GCed since it is cached. But concept wise (if short value wasn't being returned from the cache), OP could end up with 2 Objects that are eligible for GC.